# Kperf build failing

Tags: go, build, knative

I've tried to Build [kperf](https://github.com/knative-sandbox/kperf) by running build.sh, but I get The following error with unable to find io/fs. I'm a huge go noob, any help appreciated.

```
ibrahim@home:~/kperf/src/knative.dev/kperf$ ./hack/build.sh
⚖️ License
 Format
 Compile
knative.dev/kperf/pkg/config imports
        github.com/spf13/viper imports
        io/fs: cannot find module providing package io/fs
-mod=mod not supported (can be '', 'readonly', or 'vendor')
/home/ibrahim/kperf/src/knative.dev/kperf/hack/build-funcs.sh: line 44: go-bindata: command not found
-mod=mod not supported (can be '', 'readonly', or 'vendor')
 Test
knative.dev/kperf/pkg/config imports
        github.com/spf13/viper imports
        io/fs: cannot find module providing package io/fs
-mod=mod not supported (can be '', 'readonly', or 'vendor')
/home/ibrahim/kperf/src/knative.dev/kperf/hack/build-funcs.sh: line 44: go-bindata: command not found
build io/fs: cannot load io/fs: open /home/ibrahim/kperf/src/knative.dev/kperf/vendor/io/fs: no such file or directory
 Failure
```

### Steps to reproduce:

1. Create and cd into /kperf/src/knative.dev directory
2. Clone Kperf project
3. cd into kperf project directory and run ./hack/build.sh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message means that your Go tool

- does not support `-mod=mod` (module support was introduced as an experimental feature in [Go1.11](https://go.dev/doc/go1.11#modules)).
- does not have the package `io/fs` (which was added in [Go1.16](https://go.dev/doc/go1.16#fs)).

That indicates the Go tool installed on your system is too old.

According to the go directive in [the go.mod file](https://github.com/knative-sandbox/kperf/blob/50dadbe47a1e134d05c640093d3568557e414ccf/go.mod), I think you should upgrade to Go1.18 at least.

```
module knative.dev/kperf

go 1.18
```

It's better to install the latest Go. See https://go.dev/doc/install
for the installation instructions.

Comment: Thank you Zeku, I was on go 1.13 and that was the problem